# JMS message receiver filtering by JMSCorrelationID

Tags: jakarta-ee, queue, jms

How can I instantiate a JMS queue listener in java (JRE /JDK / J2EE 1.4) that only receives messages that match a given JMSCorrelationID?  The messages that I'm looking to pick up have been published to a queue and not a topic, although that can change if needed.

Here's the code that I'm currently using to put the message in the queue:

```
/**
 * publishResponseToQueue publishes Requests to the Queue.
 *
 * @param   jmsQueueFactory             -Name of the queue-connection-factory
 * @param   jmsQueue                    -The queue name for the request
 * @param   response                     -A response object that needs to be published
 * 
 * @throws  ServiceLocatorException     -An exception if a request message
 *                                      could not be published to the Topic
 */
private void publishResponseToQueue( String jmsQueueFactory,
                                    String jmsQueue,
                                    Response response )
        throws ServiceLocatorException {

    if ( logger.isInfoEnabled() ) {
        logger.info( "Begin publishRequestToQueue: " +
                         jmsQueueFactory + "," + jmsQueue + "," + response );
    }
    logger.assertLog( jmsQueue != null && !jmsQueue.equals(""),
                      "jmsQueue cannot be null" );
    logger.assertLog( jmsQueueFactory != null && !jmsQueueFactory.equals(""),
                      "jmsQueueFactory cannot be null" );
    logger.assertLog( response != null, "Request cannot be null" );

    try {

        Queue queue = (Queue)_context.lookup( jmsQueue );

        QueueConnectionFactory factory = (QueueConnectionFactory)
            _context.lookup( jmsQueueFactory );

        QueueConnection connection = factory.createQueueConnection();
        connection.start();
        QueueSession session = connection.createQueueSession( false,
                                    QueueSession.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE );

        ObjectMessage objectMessage = session.createObjectMessage();

        objectMessage.setJMSCorrelationID(response.getID());

        objectMessage.setObject( response );

        session.createSender( queue ).send( objectMessage );

        session.close();
        connection.close();

    } catch ( Exception e ) {
        //XC3.2  Added/Modified BEGIN
        logger.error( "ServiceLocator.publishResponseToQueue - Could not publish the " +
                      "Response to the Queue - " + e.getMessage() );
        throw new ServiceLocatorException( "ServiceLocator.publishResponseToQueue " +
                                           "- Could not publish the " +
                      "Response to the Queue - " + e.getMessage() );
        //XC3.2  Added/Modified END
    }

    if ( logger.isInfoEnabled() ) {
        logger.info( "End publishResponseToQueue: " +
                         jmsQueueFactory + "," + jmsQueue + response );
    }

}  // end of publishResponseToQueue method
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The queue connection setup is the same, but once you have the QueueSession, you set the selector when creating a receiver.

```
    QueueReceiver receiver = session.createReceiver(myQueue, "JMSCorrelationID='theid'");
```

then

```
receiver.receive()
```

or

```
receiver.setListener(myListener);
```

Comment: I've been reading on the same topic recently and have a question as follows: will the receiver still receive those messages that do not contain the required correlation id and silently drop them w/o processing, or will the JMS provider itself not deliver such messages to the receiver, so that they still remain on the queue? I feel the latter is the correct approach, but want to verify. Thanks.

Comment: @Robin ... In this case the filter condition is  "JMSCorrelationID='theid'" . I need to add one more condition with this like  "JMSCorrelationID='theid'"  and "Location=ASIA". What is the syntax for this multiple filter condition

Answer (score 5):

BTW while its not the actual question you asked - if you are trying to implement request response over JMS I'd recommend [reading this article](http://activemq.apache.org/how-should-i-implement-request-response-with-jms.html) as the JMS API is quite a bit more complex than you might imagine and doing this efficiently is much harder than it looks.

In particular [to use JMS efficiently](http://activemq.apache.org/how-do-i-use-jms-efficiently.html) you should try to avoid creating consumers for a single message etc.

Also because the JMS API is so very complex to use correctly and efficiently - particularly with pooling, transactions and concurrent processing - I recommend folks [hide the middleware from their application code](http://activemq.apache.org/camel/hiding-middleware.html) such as via using [Apache Camel's Spring Remoting implementation for JMS](http://activemq.apache.org/camel/spring-remoting.html)

Comment: I'd have saved myself a lot of wheel-reinvention, had I known about Camel a couple of years ago.

Answer (score 2):

Hope this will help. I used Open MQ.

```
package com.MQueues;

import java.util.UUID;

import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.MessageProducer;
import javax.jms.QueueConnection;
import javax.jms.QueueReceiver;
import javax.jms.QueueSession;
import javax.jms.Session;
import javax.jms.TextMessage;

import com.sun.messaging.BasicQueue;
import com.sun.messaging.QueueConnectionFactory;

public class HelloProducerConsumer {

public static String queueName = "queue0";
public static String correlationId;

public static String getCorrelationId() {
    return correlationId;
}

public static void setCorrelationId(String correlationId) {
    HelloProducerConsumer.correlationId = correlationId;
}

public static String getQueueName() {
    return queueName;
}

public static void sendMessage(String threadName) {
    correlationId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    try {

        // Start connection
        QueueConnectionFactory cf = new QueueConnectionFactory();
        QueueConnection connection = cf.createQueueConnection();
        QueueSession session = connection.createQueueSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        BasicQueue destination = (BasicQueue) session.createQueue(threadName);
        MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(destination);
        connection.start();

        // create message to send
        TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage();
        message.setJMSCorrelationID(correlationId);
        message.setText(threadName + "(" + System.currentTimeMillis() 
                + ") " + correlationId +" from Producer");

        System.out.println(correlationId +" Send from Producer");
        producer.send(message);

        // close everything
        producer.close();
        session.close();
        connection.close();

    } catch (JMSException ex) {
        System.out.println("Error = " + ex.getMessage());
    }
}

public static void receivemessage(final String correlationId) {
    try {

        QueueConnectionFactory cf = new QueueConnectionFactory();
        QueueConnection connection = cf.createQueueConnection();
        QueueSession session = connection.createQueueSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

        BasicQueue destination = (BasicQueue) session.createQueue(getQueueName());

        connection.start();

        System.out.println("\n");
        System.out.println("Start listen " + getQueueName() + " " + correlationId +" Queue from receivemessage");
        long now = System.currentTimeMillis();

        // receive our message
        String filter = "JMSCorrelationID = '" + correlationId  + "'";
        QueueReceiver receiver = session.createReceiver(destination, filter);
        TextMessage m = (TextMessage) receiver.receive();
        System.out.println("Received message = " + m.getText() + " timestamp=" + m.getJMSTimestamp());

        System.out.println("End listen " + getQueueName() + " " + correlationId +" Queue from receivemessage");

        session.close();
        connection.close();

    } catch (JMSException ex) {
        System.out.println("Error = " + ex.getMessage());
    }
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    HelloProducerConsumer.sendMessage(getQueueName());
    String correlationId1 = getCorrelationId();
    HelloProducerConsumer.sendMessage(getQueueName());
    String correlationId2 = getCorrelationId();
    HelloProducerConsumer.sendMessage(getQueueName());
    String correlationId3 = getCorrelationId();


    HelloProducerConsumer.receivemessage(correlationId2);

    HelloProducerConsumer.receivemessage(correlationId1);

    HelloProducerConsumer.receivemessage(correlationId3);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String filter = "JMSCorrelationID = '" + msg.getJMSMessageID() + "'";
QueueReceiver receiver = session.createReceiver(queue, filter);
```

Here the receiver will get the messages for which `JMSCorrelationID` is equal to `MessageID`. this is very helpful in request/ response paradigm.

or you can directly set this to any value:

```
QueueReceiver receiver = session.createReceiver(queue,  "JMSCorrelationID ='"+id+"'";);
```

Than you can do either `receiver.receive(2000);` or `receiver.setMessageListener(this);`