# Get using ActiveMQ as a load balancer

Tags: rest, soap, get, jms, activemq-classic

I am trying to use ActiveMQ as a facade to hide an underlying load balanced and distributed environment. For example, suppose that we have 3 instances of the same service, running on different servers. An ActiveMQ queue hides this from the rest of the application. Also, using a network of brokers, we're able to eliminate any single points of failure.

I wanted to know, how do we perform something as simple as a Get on the underlying service?

The client connecting to this environment does not know there are multiple instances of the actual service that underlie the queue. The client is interacting directly with the queue. Therefore, when dealing directly with the queue, and not the underlying services, how does a client perform a simple Get?

Thank you!

Comment: It is essential that there are no single points of failure.

Comment: Note that I am not trying to Get messages from the queue, I am trying to perform a Get on the underlying service implementation.

Comment: What is a "get" on a service? Please provide an example.

Comment: @user2612462 Please see this question and expecting help from your side. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19706788/jersey-rest-web-service-with-activemq-middleware-integration . Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Your services are using an asynchronous interface. As a consequence you should do the same in your REST API.

1. In a `@PUT` or `@POST` method send a message to the service. This method returns at once.
2. The service starts to process the message
3. In a `@GET` method check for a message in a response queue. There is no message yet, so it returns "not yet completed"
4. The service has finished, and it sends a message on a response queue
5. Now in the `@GET` method you can read the response message, and return it to the client

Related: [JMS message receiver filtering by JMSCorrelationID](https://stackoverflow.com/q/149037/2390083)

Comment: Thanks, just to clarify, When requesting the initial '@GET', should we '@POST' a message to the queue that encapsulates the '@GET'?

Comment: If we did encapsulate as above, I presume we would need to intercept the message prior to delivering to the underlying service, so we can extract the '@GET' to feed it to the underlying service. Is that correct?

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand your comments. You should describe your scenario in detail in your question.

Comment: @Beryllium Please help on this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19706788/integration-of-restful-wvb-service-with-activemq